# ant design - Update checked value of a checkbox inside a Form.Item using Form.setFieldsValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a React Form component that receives a state object. The Form contains a couple of Form.Item components, one antd Input & one antd Checkbox. I have the following code in my Form component:

```
const RecordsForm = ({ selectedRecord, recordComponentForm }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    recordComponentForm.setFieldsValue({
      Title: selectedRecord ? selectedRecord.Title : null,
      IsCurrentRecord: selectedRecord ? selectedRecord.IsCurrentRecord : true,
    });
  }, [recordComponentForm, selectedRecord]);

  return (
    <Form
      name="seasonForm"
      autoComplete="off"
      layout={"inline"}
      form={recordComponentForm}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Title"
        name="Title"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Add a Title" }]}
      >
        <Input
          name="Title"
          placeholder="Season Title"
        />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Is Active Record"
        name="IsCurrentRecord"
        valuePropName="checked"
      >
        <Checkbox name="IsCurrentRecord" />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default RecordsForm;
```

where the supplied prop `recordComponentForm` is instantiated in the parent component: `const [recordComponentForm] = Form.useForm();`

When I run the application and force this component to reload with a new `selectedRecord`, I want the `Form.Item` Input value to change to the `Title` from the object and the `Checkbox` to reflect the `IsCurrentRecord` boolean value of the object. The object passed in looks like this:

[image]

The Title Input value changes to show the Title of the object, however the checkbox remains unchanged:

[image]

I would like the checkbox to change it's `checked` value depending on what comes in on the `selectedRecord.IsCurrentRecord` object in the same way the Title does. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe.. just simply remove `name` from Checkbox.

```
<Form.Item
  label="Is Active Record"
  name="IsCurrentRecord"
  valuePropName="checked"
  >
  <Checkbox />
</Form.Item>
```

Checkbox usually return a value of choices (not boolean), so you perhaps should use Switch component instead.
But by using `valuePropName="checked"`, we could get boolean from Checkbox.

Comment: `valuePropName` is specifically needed for `Checkbox` because it doesn't use a `value` prop. Thank you for this tip!

Answer (score 0):

This was simply a case of the `Form.Items` sharing the same name and the child component it contains. Once I renamed the `Form.Item` for the Checkbox to something like **`IsCurrentRecord_FI`** and referred to it as such, it started working.